# trying to find a way to familiarize myself with the structure and content of the database that sits behind a SAP PLM

Tags: database, abap, sap-erp

I am trying to find a way to familiarize myself with the structure and content of the database that sits behind a SAP PLM system via the SAP GUI (no direct access to the database) without the risk of inadvertently changing anything (read only.

I currently have permissions that allow me to run the SE16 transaction (data browser) but all of the data export functionality has been disabled. I have seen mention of transaction code SE12 (ABAP Dictionary Display) on various forums, which sounded promising but I was refused permissions to access it by the person who has to sign off all requests for accounts or changes to permissions on the project.

Should I persist with trying to get access to the SE12 transaction?

Are there other transactions I should be considering trying to get access to in addition to or instead of SE12?

Comment: I'd say this is off-topic here. Nevertheless, rejecting SE12 but providing SE16 is just stupid. If possible, try to obtain ST05 permissions at least in the testing environment, this will allow you to trace the SQL statements, which is much more helpful than just the static structural display.

Comment: Until you get your access to SE12 you can use your access to SE16 and table DD03L to see all the fields in the different tables. This also shows that allowing SE16 but not SE12 is indeed stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this was my fist time posting a question and it sounds like I posted it in the wrong place. I found the SAP Community Network and re posted there and got the answer below. It sounds like SE12 would indeed be useful, but it also sounds like trying to understand the SAP database is a fools errand. Perhaps its best to just treat it like a black box and push any work related to locating and extracting data required for external systems over to the consultants / team implementing the system.

*"
Firstly, no-one ever accesses the SAP database via anything other than the GUI.  Think about the broad spectrum of referential integrity and consider that lots of this is managed by application code that sits above the database itself, rather than database level constraints, and you realise that interacting directly with the database underneath an SAP system is asking for trouble.  SE11 and SE16 are the two transactions you will need to achieve this in the GUI.  As Arden suggests, getting access to these in the DEV system in your landscape should be easy.  If your authorisations manager is saying no, ask them to justify why.

Being blunt, I'd question the value of this endeavour.  SAP is, in very, very simple terms, a massive relational database with lots of application code hanging it all together.  Over the years, I've encountered a number of people trying to map or model the underlying SAP database schema and typically, they are barely scratching the surface before they realise the futility of the task!  When I say massive, I mean really massive.  Think 10's of thousands of tables, if not more.  Even a single module in SAP, such as PLM, could be made up of hundreds or more database objects.  And that's before we get to all of the other data dictionary objects such as views, structures, lock objects, domains, etc. etc...

Having said all this, I really don't think you are approaching SAP in the right manner and will quickly burn a lot of time getting nowhere.  Maybe it would help us to help you more if you briefly explain why you want to understand the whole data model?
"*

Answer (score 0):

To familiaize yourself with the PLM database structure, it is very helpful to connect the knowledge of a PLM transaction with the corresponding database tables and fields.

I guess you are a user and you have access to some PLM transactions.

When you are in a PLM transaction, klick on an interesting field and then in the menu

```
System -> Status
```

There is a good probability that you can do so.

There you can see the field name and the underlying table or structure. If you find it in SE16, it's a table, look what's inside. (If it's a structure:sorry). It's very often a table.

This answer is designed for your brain to connect the dots and has a good probability that you have the necessary rights when you have SE16.